# Create new column based on conditions of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I have a df like below

```
Year  IndexDate   WorkDate       ID   Name
0  2019        NaT 2018-12-12  9265299     FV
1  2019 2019-01-09 2019-01-09  9265299     OM
2  2020 2020-11-27 2020-11-27  9962241     PM
3  2020        NaT 2020-11-27  9962241  Other
4  2020        NaT 2021-01-19  9962241  Other
df.dtypes
Out[50]: 
Year                  int64
IndexDate    datetime64[ns]
WorkDate     datetime64[ns]
ID                    int64
Name                 object
dtype: object

df.to_dict()
{'Year': {0: 2018, 1: 2019, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2021}, 'IndexDate': {0: NaT, 1: Timestamp('2019-01-09 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-11-27 00:00:00'), 3: NaT, 4: NaT}, 'WorkDate': {0: Timestamp('2018-12-12 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2019-01-09 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-11-27 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-11-27 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2021-01-19 00:00:00')}, 'ID': {0: 9265299, 1: 9265299, 2: 9962241, 3: 9962241, 4: 9962241}, 'Name': {0: 'FV', 1: 'OM', 2: 'PM', 3: 'Other', 4: 'Other'}}
```

Each ID have one IndexDate. I'd like to create new Year column which will keep Year values if Name = OM or PM, if Name = FV or Other, new Year column will get year of the IndexDate instead of year of WorkDate

My expected result

```
Year  IndexDate   WorkDate       ID   Name
0  2019        NaT 2018-12-12  9265299     FV
1  2019 2019-01-09 2019-01-09  9265299     OM
2  2020 2020-11-27 2020-11-27  9962241     PM
3  2020        NaT 2020-11-27  9962241  Other
4  2020        NaT 2021-01-19  9962241  Other
```

Many thanks for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `IndexDate` eist only for rows with `OM/PM` in `Name` generate `year`s and aggregate first non missing values per `ID`:

```
df['Year'] = df['IndexDate'].dt.year.groupby(df['ID']).transform('first')
```

For general solution add [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set missing values for not matched `OM/PM` values:

```
df['Year'] = (df['IndexDate'].dt.year.where(df['Name'].isin(['OM','PM']))
                             .groupby(df['ID']).transform('first'))
```

IIUC need assign years by condition:

```
df['Year'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(['OM','PM']),
                      df['IndexDate'].dt.year, df['WorkDate'].dt.year)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that, OM or PM might have WorkDate different from IndexDate, in that case, Year takes the year of WorkDate. Only FV or Other has to take the year of IndexDate (for each ID)

Comment: Can you change input/ouput dataframe in question?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean?

Comment: @NguyenPham - do you need `np.where(df['Name'].isin(['OM','PM']), df['IndexDate'].dt.year, df['WorkDate'].dt.year)` ?

Comment: numpy.where function works well for me. Many thanks!!